# How can I check if a checkbox is checked/unchecked in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check the status of the checkbox through a method which returns a boolean but it returns false in both cases (checked and unchecked).

```
 def checkbox_status(self):
        checked=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Dell")]/parent::span').is_selected()
        return checked
```

HTML

```
<div class="a-checkbox a-checkbox-fancy s-navigation-checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" checked="">
        <i class="a-icon a-icon-checkbox"></i>
        <span class="a-label a-checkbox-label">
            <span class="a-size-base a-color-base a-text-bold">Dell</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try it with `find_element_by_name` or `find_element_by_id`?

Comment: @DirtyBit checkbox contain no name/id/class. so i used xpath to locate.

Comment: Make sure the path provided is correct.

Comment: can you post html ?

Comment: @DirtyBit  am using the same path for selecting the checkbox and it can successfully selecting it. so i hope the path is correct.

Comment: @KajalKundu please check the html code attached above.

Comment: @MuthuKumar Update the question with the HTML of the checkbox of both the states 1)Being unchecked and 2)Being checked

Answer (score 0):

We can try with get attribute. That works fine for me:

```
def status():
    element =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Dell")]/ancestor::label/input')
    if element.get_attribute('checked') :
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [is_selected](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected) method that returns a boolean

To verify or get selection status, we can use two mechanisms

`1.driver.find_element_by_id("privacypolicy").is_selected();`

This will return ‘true’ if the checkbox is selected, false if it is not selected.

`2.driver.find_element_by_id("privacypolicy").get_attribute("checked");`

This will return ‘true’ if the checkbox is selected. But will return NoneType if checkbox is not selected.

for more information click on [this](http://allselenium.info/working-with-checkboxes-using-python-selenium-webdriver/) link.

Comment: There is no element with an ID "privacypolicy" in OP's HTML. He's already using `.is_selected()`, why explain it to him?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your XPath is pointing to a `SPAN` instead of an `INPUT`. The `INPUT` is the checkbox here. If you switch your XPath to point to the `INPUT`, it should work just fine.

```
def checkbox_status(self):
    return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input/following::span[.='Dell'][1]').is_selected()
```

XPath explanation

```
//input/following::span[.='Dell'][1]
^ find an INPUT
       ^ that is followed by a SPAN
                       ^ that contains the text "Dell"
                                 ^ return only the nearest one
```

NOTE: I combined the two lines of code since there's no need here to assign the element to a variable and then return that variable. Just return the result of the find.

---

To answer DebanjanB's question from the comments about the `[1]` in the XPath I'm using. Here's a simple demo. I start with the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

If I use the XPath `//ul/li`, it returns all 3 `LI`s. If I add a `[1]` to the XPath to give `//ul/li[1]`, now it returns only the closest `LI`. This is useful when looking up or down the DOM. In some instances it isn't necessary because you can just use `.find_element()` (singular) but I've found that in IE this doesn't always work as expected. I haven't fully tested and documented the differences but I think it's basically that in some browsers if the position isn't in the XPath, it will return a collection where the first element is the closest element but in IE it will return the same collection but the first element is at the TOP of the DOM rather than the closest. After figuring that out the hard way, I started just putting the `[1]` inside the XPath and it seems to work consistently (at least on the browsers that I maintain).

The `[1]` I'm using is a alias for `position()`. You can read more about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position).

Comment: Can you throw some light how `[1]` within a `By` refers to **return only the nearest one**?

Comment: @DebanjanB Sure. I added some extra info in the question and a link to more reference material.

Answer (score -2):

I have used is_displayed() instead of is_selected() to assert the status of the checkbox. It is working fine.

```
def checkbox_status(self):
    checked=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Dell")]/parent::span/parent::label/input[@checked]').is_displayed()
    return checked
```

Comment: is_displayed return true if element is visible and do not have any relation to selected status. Please share HTML with selected and not selected statuses